# Editing properties of an SKSpriteNode custom class?

Tags: swift, swift3, sprite-kit, swift-playground

In my custom SKSpriteNode class, I want to be able to change properties such as anchorPoint, posistion, etc. within the custom class so I don't need to elsewhere.

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

open class Crank:SKSpriteNode {

init() {
    super.init(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "crank"), color:     
        NSColor.white, size: CGSize(width: 155.0, height: 188.0))

    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

How would I edit other properties?

Comment: I really don't understand what do you need to do.. If you want change some properties, simply initialize your sprite then change these properties: it's better to change some basic properties to the context where they are presents, not inside the custom class.

Answer (score 1):

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class Crank: SKSpriteNode {

    init(imageNamed image: String, position at: CGPoint, withAnchor anchor: CGPoint) {

        super.init(imageNamed: image)
        self.position = position
        self.anchorPoint = anchor
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

(Written from memory, so may contain small errors, but is broadly correct).

and then in your main code:

```
let myCrank = Crank(imageNamed: "Crank.png", at: CGPoint(300, 500), withAnchor: CGpointZero)
```

My answer notwithstanding, Alessandro has a point. I think that it's better to set 'standard' properties in the normal place.

If you are going to set any of the standard SKSpriteNode properties inside the actual class, then I think specifying them in an initialiser is good practice as it makes the m more visible,. Debugging a program where you don't appears to set a node's position, or texture etc. would be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it would be to create a protocol and apply it to the standard SpriteKit classes that you are subclassing (or their ancestor).

For example:

```
protocol CustomSKNode
{
    var position:CGFloat  { get set }
    var zRotation:CGFloat { get set }
    // ...
}
extension SKNode: CustomSKNode {}
```

Once you've done this somewhere in your project, you'll be able to access these properties of on any of your custom SKNode or SKSpriteNode without having to import SpriteKit.